# Rules for entering Germany from Poland?

Tags: germany, poland, quarantine

I recently reached Poland with D type visa. Now I want to go to Germany by train. I just need to fill out that form or I need to have the test also? I know there is quarantine for 10 days.

Comment: Since the 9th of May Poland is considered a risk country, therefore a test and possible quarantine is required.

Comment: So before this date it was not risk country? The situation is getting really better here  I think before this date Poland was considered as a high risk or dangerous (sth like this) no?

Comment: Poland was considered a **high risk** area between the 21st of March to the 8th of May.  [RKI - Coronavirus SARS-CoV-2 - Informationen zur Ausweisung internationaler Risikogebiete durch das Auswärtige Amt, BMG und BMI](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over